# View data only before or after a specific date?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I want to know two solutions (based on the date of membership registration).

1. Inquiry data after membership date.
2. Inquiry data before date of membership date.

I used the session to import membership date data `($_SESSION['date'])` and would like to compare it with `"DATE_FORMAT (DATE_TranDate,%Y-%m-%d').`

The query statement is as follows.

```sql
$sql = "SELECT id,  DATE_FORMAT(tranDate,'%Y-%m-%d') as tranDate, tranTime, date, cmd, paymethod, amount, orgRefNo, orgTranDate, applNo 
FROM noti_card_data  
WHERE  ($card_mbr) 
LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
```

Comment: Hi. Please give us preview of data in your variable $_SESSION['date']

Comment: $_SESSION['date']  is 2020-06-15

Comment: if the dates are the same format, just "WHERE date1>=date2" and/or "WHERE date1<=date2"

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62465933/edit) to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE noti_card_data; ` result and a few rows of example data. Also show us (in text/table format) your expected output.